# no data with Puma and NewRelic ruby agent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, newrelic, puma

I have Puma webserver, my app can't send data for newrelic. Only I see the data from Browser page but not for other activities  like app server response or errors.

This is my log:

```
INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
INFO : Environment: staging
INFO : Dispatcher: puma
INFO : Application: myapp_puma
INFO : Installing Authlogic instrumentation
INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
INFO : Installing Puma cluster mode support
INFO : Installing Sinatra instrumentation
INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
INFO : Installing Resque instrumentation
INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
INFO : Finished instrumentation
INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/105527/applications/2683478
INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the latest version of the new relic gem
2. Log in to your new relic account and download a fresh, customized YAML config file under settings
3. Load the new relic gem as the last thing in you gemfile

What type of app is it? Your logs show both Sinatra and rails, which version of ruby and where are you hosting it?

Comment: Sorry, I did that but I can get good instrumentation in newrelic. My app is with: rails 3.2.13 / nginx / puma. I'm using http with balancers in amazon. I used to have unicorn and with this work fine the instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

I work at New Relic.

That log is unfortunately not verbose enough to tell us much that is useful.  I can tell by looking at your account that you are in fact running the latest version of the agent, which does support puma (clustered and not) by default.

Since we can't really have a conversation here, could you open a support ticket at  support.newrelic.com and send us debug-level logs (change log_level to debug in newrelic.yml), from time of app start-up through receiving some traffic?

Comment: Hello, I change the log_level to debug, and I get other important info, but I dont even get browser and app data.

DEBUG : Beacon configuration is nil. Skipping browser instrumentation.

production:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
  ssl: false

Answer (score 0):

I found that specifying workers, daemonizing and preloading the app works for me...

**puma-config.rb**

```
environment 'production'
workers 1                            
threads 8, 16
daemonize true
preload_app!
```